# tinymce : Remove css styles from style attribute

Tags: css, tinymce

I am trying to configure tinymce to not allow css styles in style attribute.

I just want to allow one style which is text-decoration. Here is a similar problem 
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=76101 .

The valid_styles option is not present and I dont want to use regexp on my content, coz there got to be some or the other option with tinymce. I searched through the tinymce forums but couldn't find any proper solution.

Can anybody help?

Comment: this applies only to copy+paste?

Comment: yes... when you paste content from external source

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is tu use the **[paste plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/paste)** and do some prefiltering when performing **copy+paste** into the editor.

Use the **paste_preprocess** setting in your init, using your own cleanup mechanism here:

```
paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) {
    o.content = custom_function_modify(o.content);
},
```